# Undo functionality for QPainter drawEllipse() function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qpainter

I'm new to PyQt and started playing around with some online code. The `drawEllipse()` function found in `QPainter` class draws an ellipse based on defined parameters. My question is once we call the function and it draws it on our scene, how do I undo this operation? There seems to be no such function that can do this in the documentation.

Example drawing code:

```
def draw(self, x, y):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.image)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(y,x),10,10)
        painter.end()
        self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
```

So if a keystroke of `Ctrl+Z` is pressed this drawn circle should disappear, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you use `QImage` because if you want to graph circles you should use `QGraphicsEllipseItem`.

To implement the undo method we must store the items in a list, then when you call the undo method you get the last element and remove it from the `QGraphicsScene` using `removeItem()`.

In the following example, a circle is added each time you click.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.gv = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        lay.addWidget(self.gv)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 400, 400)
        self.gv.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gv.installEventFilter(self)

        self.items = []

        shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+Z"), self)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.undo)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.gv and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            p = self.gv.mapToScene(event.pos())
            self.draw(p)
        return QtWidgets.QWidget.eventFilter(self, obj, event)

    def draw(self, p):
        it = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 10, 10)
        it.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        self.scene.addItem(it)
        it.setPos(p)
        self.items.append(it)

    def undo(self):
        if self.items:
            it = self.items.pop()
            self.scene.removeItem(it)
            del it


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! I din't know the difference since I just started.